# Prove that all the subsequent triangles formed by the particles will have same or common centroid

Tags: kinematics, vectors

originial question in the book.
" three particles A, B and C are situated at the vertices of an equilateral triangle $ABC$ of side d at time t=0.Each of the particles moves with constant speed v.A always has its velocity along AB,B along BC and C along CA.At what time will they meet each other?"

Source.
This question is from *Concepts of physics 1, HC verma* ,kinematics,solved   example20

Image of the figure.
[image]

My question.

In the solution of the original question in the book, it is assumed that through symmetry, the  three particles will meet at the centroid of the original equilateral triangle and the subsequent triangle formed by the  coordinates of the three particles will be equilateral, and  all the subsequent traingle along with the original triangle will have a common centroid. I am looking for a formal proof for the same.

My attempt.
The velocity of $A$ is $v$ along $AB$. The velocity of $B$ is along $BC$. Its component along $BA$ is $\cos60=v/2$. Thus, separation $AB$ decreases at the rate $v+v/2=3v/2$. Similarly, the separation $BC$ and $CA$ decreases at the rate $3v/2$. Hence, all the subsequent triangle formed are equilateral as the all three separation decrease at the same rate.
I am unable to prove the rest.

Comment: Please type out your question. Crop and rotate your figures to what is essential. Give references and show some effort toward the problem.

Comment: Great start. Next:  Give references and show some effort toward the problem.

Comment: Why do the particles follow curved paths? Is there a force you didn't tell us about? But if so why is the question about kinematics not dynamics?

Comment: "I have edited it again." Keep editing. It still looks pretty bad. In particular, maybe start with, oh I don't know, maybe the first letter of the first sentence...

Answer (score 2):

Let the vector positions of the three particles be $\mathbf{r}_A$, $\mathbf{r}_B$, and $\mathbf{r}_C$. By definition, the location of the centroid is
$$\mathbf{r}_{\mathrm{cen}} = \frac{\mathbf{r}_A + \mathbf{r}_B + \mathbf{r}_C}{3}.$$
The velocity of the centroid is
$$\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{cen}} = \frac{\mathbf{v}_A + \mathbf{v}_B + \mathbf{v}_C}{3} = \frac{v}{3} \left( \hat{\mathbf{v}}_A + \hat{\mathbf{v}}_B + \hat{\mathbf{v}}_C \right).$$
As you have already shown, the three particles lie on an equilateral triangle, so $\hat{\mathbf{v}}_A + \hat{\mathbf{v}}_B + \hat{\mathbf{v}}_C = 0$, and the centroid stays at the same place.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $A,B,C$ always form an equilateral triangle of centroid $O$ comes from the invariance by a $2\pi/3$ rotation about $O$. The initial condition satisfies this condition and the equation of motion as well, so the relevant solution is invariant satisfies it.

Using the invariance by rotation, you can also easily see that if two points coincide, they all coincide, and this coincidence will be $O$ (only fixed point of the rotation).

In fact the convergence to the origin can be established also by direct calculation using polar coordinates $(r,\phi)$ of one point say $A$ (which is enough to specify the entire system) with respect to $O$. This shadows you original approach, and even gives you the moment of convergence. You get the equations:
$$
\dot r = -\frac{v\sqrt 3}{2} \\
r\dot \phi = \frac{v}{2}
$$
using
$$\sin\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{1}{2} \\ \cos\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}
$$
So $r=0$ at $t= \frac{2r_0}{v\sqrt 3}$. Btw, by solving the equation for $\phi$, you’ll see that the trajectory is actually a logarithmic spiral as can be seen in the drawing.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
start position vectors of points $~1~,2~,3~$ , where the coordinate system is at the center of mass
\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{R}_{10}\begin{bmatrix}
  -\frac 12\,a \\
  \frac{h}{3} \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
&\mathbf{R}_{20}= \begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  -\frac{2\,h}{3} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&\mathbf{R}_{30}=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac 12\,a \\
  \frac{h}{3} \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
&\text{with}~h=a\,\sin(\varphi)
\end{align*}
$~a~$ is the triangle side  and $~\varphi=\frac{\pi}{3}~$

each point move towards the tangent $~\mathbf t~$  with velocity $~v~$ hence

\begin{align*}
 &\mathbf{R}_{1i}(t)=\mathbf{R}_{1\,i-1}+i\,\Delta t\,v\,\mathbf{t}_{21}\quad,
 \mathbf{t}_{21}=\frac{\mathbf{R}_{2i}-\mathbf{R_{1i}}}{|\mathbf{R}_{2i}-\mathbf{R_{1i}}|}\\
 &\mathbf{R}_{2i}(t)=\mathbf{R}_{2\,i-1}+i\,\Delta t\,v\,\mathbf{t}_{23}\quad,
 \mathbf{t}_{23}=\frac{\mathbf{R}_{3i}-\mathbf{R_{2i}}}{|\mathbf{R}_{3i}-\mathbf{R_{2i}}|}\\
 &\mathbf{R}_{3i}(t)=\mathbf{R}_{3\,i-1}+i\,\Delta t\,v\,\mathbf{t}_{31}\quad,
 \mathbf{t}_{31}=\frac{\mathbf{R}_{3i}-\mathbf{R_{1i}}}{|\mathbf{R}_{3i}-\mathbf{R_{1i}}|}
\end{align*}
where $~i~$ the number of points  and  $~\Delta t~$  the time step.

the "new"  triangle is the connection $~\mathbf{R}_{1i}(t)\rightarrow\mathbf{R}_{2i}(t)\rightarrow\mathbf{R}_{3i}(t)~$.
if these triangles are isosceles triangles the angles $~\theta_i~$  between two sides $~\mathbf{R}_{ai}~,\mathbf{R}_{bi}~$  must be $~\theta_i=\frac{\pi}{3}~$
this can obtain with law of cosines

\begin{align*}
  &\cos(\theta_i)=\frac{\mathbf{R}_{ai}\cdot\,\mathbf{R}_{bi}}{|\mathbf{R}_{ai}|\,|\mathbf{R}_{bi}|}=\frac 12\quad\Rightarrow ~\theta_i=\frac{\pi}{3}
\end{align*}

hence
the connection of all points are isosceles triangles

Comment: Now do $\Delta t \to 0$ please^^ this probably does not look as good with bigger steps right? I think this might lead to a nicer proof. It's really useful for getting ideas, to just do a quick computer model. Just to share: this thing still works if we go to half the distance every time for example basically the opposite of $\Delta t \to 0$, that may be useful for a more analytical proof. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Kuhlambo the angle $~\theta~$ is independent of the step size. The analytical solution for $~\cos(\theta_i)~$ is for each point 1\2

Comment: Oh interesting, thanks. I'll think about that.